# meta viewport tag not working in window phone IE browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design, windows-phone

To detect the user agent i am using below script. It seems window phone ignores the meta viewport tag. Have any one else encounter with same problem. basically i want to zoom out the page in all mobile devices.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iemobile/i)) {
    document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=0.25" />');

}
```

also tried:

```
|| navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
```

navigator.userAgent is working i checked it through alert but viewport meta and its properties are not working. I am not getting the zoom out page although i have added initial-scale=0.25

Every thing comes as expected in all mobile devices except the window phone.

Comment: Can't you check what value you got for `navigator.userAgent` in your problematic case?

Comment: navigator.userAgent is working i checked it through alert but viewport meta and its properties are not working. I am not getting the zoom out page although i have added initial-scale=0.25

Comment: Okay, wasn't clear for me (due to your sentence "also tried: `|| navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)`"

Answer (score 0):

For IE 10  you can try this

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
```

and initial-scale works only in **portrait** mode for IE check the [compactibality in quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/)

Comment: user agent for IE is working but viewport meta tag is not. I applied alert under userAgent and alert is working but viewport not ex. initial-scale.

Comment: initial-scale works only in portrait mode for IE http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/